# validating check boxes in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used check box in gridview . Now i want to validate those checkboxes as if no check box is selected a message shud pop up saying please select check box and thn press submit

Thanks 
Smartdev

Comment: What code have you already gotten? What doesn't work? I will not do your work for you.

Comment: Then why even comment on the question - if you don't want to help, move along. Some questions like this one, are very hard to show code because usually the solution is only two lines.

Comment: In addition to the requests from Oded - how are you validating the checkboxes?  Javascript on the client side or server side through a postback?

Comment: Its my bad i was not clear on question i think ..i want to validate the check boxes so that without  checking the check box  user should not submit data  .rite now not im not  using anything ..i wanted to know the best and easy way . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [CustomValidator](https://web.archive.org/web/20200923030537/http://geekswithblogs.net/davewill/archive/2008/09/04/124931.aspx) which validates if the user checked the Checkbox. You must set ValidateEmptyText to true. Following an example which you can rewrite easily  to validate a Checkbox: [CustomValidator in a GridView with a ValidationSummary control](https://web.archive.org/web/20200923030537/http://geekswithblogs.net/davewill/archive/2008/09/04/124931.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial [here](http://programming.top54u.com/post/ASP-Net-GridView-Checkbox-Javascript-Validation.aspx) that will walk you through how to perform validation using Javascript on the client side.

You can easily modify the logic with in the javascript to throw up an alert if no boxes are checked.

IMO client side validation would be better as it will save a trip to the server.

In addition, you could implement the [AJAX Mutually Exclusive CheckBox](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/MutuallyExclusiveCheckBox/MutuallyExclusiveCheckBox.aspx) in the GridView item template to force users to check a maximum of one box.  However, from your question I'm not 100% sure if you require this.